# Limit number of events in fullCalendar

Tags: javascript, ajax, fullcalendar

I am using fullCalendar in my project.I am facing issue to limit number of events in a day.I had found fullCalendar plugin  https://github.com/lyconic/fullcalendar.viewmore but I am unable to customize it as it is sending control in ajax to some unknown file "/test/get-events"

```
    events: function(start, end, callback) {
        $.ajax({
          url: '/test/get-events',
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function(data){
            callback(data);
          }
        });
```

When I tried to change url to get my event,fullCalendar doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried using [eventLimit](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventLimit)?